# Should I use "could" or "would" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> She stared at her phone for a minute she wished **could/would**
>   stretch until infinity.

Should it be could or would? Or maybe both but would mean different things?

Comment: If you edit your question to explain what you already know about "could" and "would", and why that doesn't help with this sentence, we should be able to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She stared at her phone for a minute she wished could/would stretch until infinity.

I think both choices are correct, but "would" would be the better word use here. Sure, the minute *could* have the ability to stretch on forever, but that doesn't mean it *would* for sure.

To add onto SovereignSun's comment, this sentence may read fine in context, but sounds a little confusing on its own, at least to me; try

> She stared at her phone for a minute **that** she wished would stretch until infinity.

Or something else to that effect.